# Check if an element exists in a list of a different class in Java

Tags: java, list, search, instanceof

This is more than a doubt, since I have tried the traditional method for it and frankly I cannot obtain a satisfactory result. Is it possible to make a method that tells me if the element of a list (of an alternative class to the method) is present? That is, I want in a "Method.java" class to make a method that tells me if an element of the list found in the "List.java" class is present or not.

```
package linearsearch;

public class linealSearch {
    public boolean elementList() {
        for(Integer integer : this.list)
            if(list instanceOf 12)
        return true;
        return false;  
    }
}
```

Comment: What does _`if(list instanceOf 12)`_ supposed to mean?

Comment: @AndrewS Oh! It was because I wanted to know if the element "12" was in the list.

Comment: It seems you're mixing up checking type with a value.  Based on the code, `list` is apparently a list that contains `Integer`s (type).  Sounds like [List.contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) could be used here, e..g, `list.contains(12)`.